# Configure Oracle fetch size from domain.xml or persistence.xml

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

I hava a JavaEE application running on Payara 5 (initial release) and I'm trying to configure the fetch size of the Oracle JDBC driver (version 12.1.0.1.0). I can change the fetch size for individual queries with a query hint, however, I'm at a loss as to how I would set a default fetch size value for the whole application. According to the Oracle documentation it can be achieved by setting the `defaultRowPrefetch` JDBC property, but I don't see a way to set this from the `domain.xml` or `persistence.xml`. The following did not work:

- configuring a property `eclipselink.jdbc.property.defaultRowPrefetch` in the persistence.xml has no effect
- configuring a `connectionAttributes` property with a value of `;defaultRowPrefetch=100` or `:100` on the connection pool also has no effect
- configuring a `connectionProperties` property on the pool causes various exceptions on startup - I tried different syntax from various SO answers for the property value but that only changed what type of exception I got

What would be the correct way to configure the default fetch size?

Comment: I just added a `-Doracle.jdbc.defaultRowPrefetch=N` to the JVM launch options of Apache Drill and I do _think_ it has done the trick.  My large result transfer speed problem has since vanished, at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page [1] it does not work only by configuration.

> You cannot set defaultRowPrefetch as a JVM property. It would have to be named
>   oracle.jdbc.defaultRowPrefetch for that to work. You can only use this property
>   by loading it into a Properties object in the code and then calling
>   getConnection with the Properties object.

Reason:

> defaultRowPrefetch is a property of the connection and not of the
>   datasource

Maybe if you found the right place in the source code in Payara that does call `getConnection()` you can check whether there is the possibility to pass this via the domain.xml.

[1] https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-defaultrowprefetch-oracle-jdbc-driver

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that link seems to be rather specific to websphere. According to the Oracle documentation I should be able to configure it with the `setConnectionProperties` method of the JDBC driver, and I can pass _something_ to that method by setting the `connectionProperties` property of the pool, but that causes an Exception (as the method expects a `Properties` object and glassfish seems to pass a String or null no matter what I do). The conclusion that it's not possible to do might be correct but I would not take the IBM link as evidence for it...

Comment: Is there an Exception stack trace? If yes, can you post it?

Comment: I get different stacktraces depending on how I try to set the value but none seem to be relevant. For `value=";defaultRowPrefetch=100"` I get a `ResourceException: Arguments are wrong for the method :  setConnectionProperties`; which I assume is due to payara trying to pass a String argument to a method which takes a Properties object. Trying to omit the `value` attribute and using spring-like syntax with `props` subelements leads to a message "error.creating.jdbc.pool" followed by a `NameNotFoundException` for the pool lookup.

Comment: Why do you put a semicolon in front of the property? Did you also try to set the properties through the admin web console?

Comment: The leading semicolon is taken from examples such as the `connectionAttributes` property in the timer pool where key-value pairs are passed in a property value; omitting it does not make a difference. The admin web console is not useful as it only has a String field for the value and setting a property there is the same as creating a `<property>` element with the respective `name` and `value` attributes by hand.